# How to validate xml with a XSD import/include other XSD files?

Tags: xml, xsd

**The root one:**

```
a.xsd
```

Which **imports | includes:**

```
<xsd:import schemaLocation="b.xsd"/>
<xsd:include schemaLocation="c.xsd"/>
```

I know there are lots of online tools (validator) can have one XML file and **a single one .xsd** file as input and run the validation.

Considering the "import" and "include" are involved, what are the options to validate an XML file by just specify a single .xsd file?

Which GUI tool (a free one) can be used to do a quick validation?
How to implement in code  of any one of the languages Java/C#/C++/Python?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The answer is simple: put following files in the same folder.

   - a.xsd
   - b.xsd
   - c.xsd
2. I've wrote a Validator.py with following contents:

   ```
   import sys
   from lxml import etree
   doc = etree.parse(sys.argv[1])
   xmlschema_doc = etree.parse('a.xsd')
   xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)
   if xmlschema(doc):
       print 'Success!'
   else:
       print 'Invalid!'
       xmlschema.assertValid(doc)
   raw_input()
   ```
3. Execute in command line (Windows):

   ```
   python Validator.py aParser.xml
   ```

Comment: Perfect solution to quickly find what wrong in an xml. Strange this was downvoted!